# Passing minContextSlot value in getSignaturesForAddress RPC method does not filter transactions

Tags: rpc, getsignaturesforaddress

I'm using the solana/web3.js library (I tried both Alchemy and Quicknode endpoints). When I try to filter the results on `getSignaturesForAddress` using `minContextSlot` passing a specific slot (for example, 173290599), it returns the same result as when I omit this option (i.e., all transactions without filtering).

I've tried using both Quicknode and Alchemy for the RPC connection. Here is the code:

```
const signatures = await this.solanaConnection.getSignaturesForAddress(pubKey, { minContextSlot: fromSlot });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is some unclear behavior about how `minContextSlot` works. It's meant to check that the RPC node is at least up to a certain slot to avoid accessing stale data, and not as a filtering mechanism.

If you wanted to add the functionality, it would be really easy! You just need to add a new filtering parameter on the `get_signatures_for_address` RPC, and then change the `highest_slot` to that new parameter in this line: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/bd9b311c630a10bb5c16b567e51bd61c21aabff9/rpc/src/rpc.rs#L1591, so you'd do:

```
let request_slot = // something passed in to the function
blockstore.get_confirmed_signatures_for_address2(address, request_slot, before, until, limit)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to implement it with the current API, you could use `connection.getBlock(minSlot - j)` with j=1.. until you hit a block, extract one of the transactions from it and pass its signature to `until`.

Or you choose the pragmatic version and filter the return value of `getSignaturesForAddress` using `item.slot >= minSlot`.